# How to send a simple message using a twilio number with an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I am trying to change and edit the code but it returns with exceptions errors in regards authentication errors. The username cannot be null as well as the category is not able to load the code. Another exception that is running on it is the Twilio.Exceptions.ApiExecution that requires a phone number.

The documentation is here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/server-notifications-csharp-mvc?code-sample=code-csv-list-of-phone-numbers-to-notify&code-language=csv&code-sdk-version=default

The video to build the code for integrating Twilio in an ASP.net MVC project is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndxQXnoDIj8

The code excerpt is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using System.Configuration;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;
using Twilio.TwiML;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace SendandReceiveSms.Controllers
{
    public class SMSController : TwilioController
    {
        // GET: SMS
        public ActionResult SendSms()
        {
      var accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSid"];
      var authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];
      TwilioClient.Init("ACa4XXXXXXXXXX","77XXXXXXXXXX");
      var to = new PhoneNumber(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["+65XXXXXXXX"]);
      var from = new PhoneNumber("+12053016835");
      var message = MessageResource.Create(
        to: to, 
        from: from,
        body: "Conserve with us and save the Wolrd ");
            return Content(message.Sid);
        }
    public ActionResult ReceiveSms()
    {
      var response = new MessagingResponse();
      response.Message(" We turn waste into environmental assets");
      return TwiML(response);
    }

    }
  }
```

Comment: what's this? var to = new PhoneNumber(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["+65XXXXXXXX"]);? is the "+65XXXXXX" a key in your ConfigurationManager?

Comment: @daxsorbito: maybe. I think apparently is it the numbers I use to send the message so I am not sure if I did them right.

Comment: can you change it to just `var to = new PhoneNumber("+65XXXXXXXX");`... and see if it fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this also.

```
 using DocGen.Notifications.Contract;
        using DocGen.Notifications.Models;
        using System;
        using System.Configuration;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using Twilio;
        using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
        using Twilio.Types;

        namespace DocGen.Notifications.Providers
        {
            public class SmsNotificationProvider : INotificationProtocolContract
            {
                NotificationResponseModel notificationResponseModel = new NotificationResponseModel();
                public NotificationResponseModel SendNotification(NotificationRequestModel notificationRequestModel)
                {
                    if (notificationRequestModel.SmsTo == null || notificationRequestModel.SmsTo.Count() == 0)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(notificationRequestModel.SmsTo));

                    TwilioClient.Init(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountSid"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authToken"]);

                    foreach (var Sms_to in notificationRequestModel.SmsTo)
                    {
                        var to = new PhoneNumber(Sms_to);
                        var message = MessageResource.Create(
                            to,
                            from: new PhoneNumber(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderNumber"]),//"+12563054795"
                            body: Encoding.UTF8.GetString(notificationRequestModel.Message));

                        notificationResponseModel.ResponseMessage = message.Status.ToString();
                    }

                    //notificationResponseModel.ResponseMessage = "Message Successfully sent.";

                    return notificationResponseModel;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I will work on them and let you know if that works.